# Evaluating an integral using Simpson's Rule

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, numerical-methods, simpsons-rule

Below is a problem I made up and did. I would be interested in feed back from the group on the quality of my answer. Does breaking up the integral in two parts make sense?

Problem:

Give an estimate of the following integral using Simpson's Rule to within 1%.
$$ \int_0^5 x^8 \,\, dx $$
Answer:

Observe that the function  is growing rapidly when $x$ is large. So, my plan is to break the integral in
two parts and evaluate each integral separately.
$$ \int_0^5 x^8 \,\, dx =  \int_0^4 x^8 \,\, dx + \int_4^5 x^8 \,\, dx $$
Let $S_1$ and $S_2$ be the estimates for the two integrals respectively. Let $S$ be the Simpson's rule estimate
for the original integral. We have $S = S_1 + S_2$. The first step is to compute $S_1$. We have:
\begin{align*}
a &= 0 \\
b &= 4 \\
n &= 8 \\
h &= \frac{b-a}{n} = \frac{4-0}{8} = \frac{1}{2} \\
S_1 &= \left( \frac{h}{3} \right) \left( f(0) + 4f\left(  \frac{1}{2} \right)  + 2f(1) + 4f \left(  \frac{3}{2} \right)
 + 2f( 2 ) + 4f\left(  \frac{5}{2} \right) 
 + 2f( 3 ) + 4f\left(  \frac{7}{2} \right) + f(4) \right) \\
f(0) &= 0 \\
f\left( \frac{1}{2 }\right) &= \frac{1}{256} \\
f(1) &= 1 \\
S_1 &= \left( \frac{1}{6} \right) \left( 4 + 4\left(  \frac{1}{256} \right)  + 2(1) + 4f \left(  \frac{3}{2} \right)
 + 2f( 2 ) + 4f\left(  \frac{5}{2} \right) 
 + 2f( 3 ) + 4f\left(  \frac{7}{2} \right) + f(4) \right) \\
S_1 &= \left( \frac{1}{6} \right) \left( 6 +  \frac{1}{64}  + 4f \left(  \frac{3}{2} \right)
 + 2f( 2 ) + 4f\left(  \frac{5}{2} \right) 
 + 2f( 3 ) + 4f\left(  \frac{7}{2} \right) + f(4) \right) \\
f\left( \frac{3}{2 }\right) &= \frac{6165}{256} \\
f(2) &= 256 \\
%
S_1 &= \left( \frac{1}{6} \right) \left( 6 +  \frac{1}{64}  + 4 \left( \frac{6165}{256} \right)
 + 2(256) + 4f\left(  \frac{5}{2} \right) 
 + 2f( 3 ) + 4f\left(  \frac{7}{2} \right) + f(4) \right) \\
%
f\left(  \frac{5}{2} \right) &= \frac{ 5^8 } { 256 } \\
f(3) &= 3^8 = 6561 \\
S_1 &= \left( \frac{1}{6} \right) \left( 6 +  \frac{1}{64}  + \left( \frac{6165}{64} \right)
 + 512 + 4\left(  \frac{ 5^8 } { 256 } \right) 
 + 2( 6561 ) + 4f\left(  \frac{7}{2} \right) + f(4) \right) \\
S_1 &= \left( \frac{1}{6} \right) \left( 518 +  \frac{1}{64}  + \left( \frac{6165}{64} \right)
  + \left(  \frac{ 5^8 } { 64 } \right) 
  + 13122 + 4f\left(  \frac{7}{2} \right) + f(4) \right) \\
f\left(  \frac{7}{2} \right) &= \frac{7^8 } {256 } \\
f(4) &= 4^8 = 65536 \\
S_1 &= \left( \frac{1}{6} \right) \left( 518 +  \frac{1}{64}  + \left( \frac{6165}{64} \right)
  + \left(  \frac{ 5^8 } { 64 } \right) 
  + 13122 + 4\left(   \frac{7^8 } {256 }  \right) + 65536 \right) \\
\end{align*}
Now finding $S_1$ is arithmetic. We will be switching to decimal numbers, hence our answer will only be an estimate.
\begin{align*}
S_1 &= \left( \frac{1}{6} \right) \left( 518 + \left( \frac{6166}{64} \right)
  + \left(  \frac{ 390625} { 64 } \right) 
  + 13122 + 4\left(   \frac{5764801 } {256 }  \right) + 65536 \right) \\
%
S_1 &\doteq \left( \frac{1}{6} \right) \left( 518 + 96.34375 + \left(  \frac{ 390625} { 64 } \right) 
    + 13122 + \left(   \frac{5764801 } {64 }  \right) + 65536 \right) \\
%
S_1 &\doteq \left( \frac{1}{6} \right) \left( 518 + 96.34375 + \left(  \frac{ 390625} { 64 } \right) 
    + 13122 + 90075.016 + 65536 \right) \\
S_1 &\doteq \left( \frac{1}{6} \right) \left( 518 + 96.34375 + 6103.5156 + 13122 + 90075.016 + 65536 \right) \\
S_1 &\doteq \left( \frac{1}{6} \right) \left( 175450.88 \right) \\
S_1 &\doteq 29241.813 \\
\end{align*}
As a partial check, we compute the exact value of the integral.
$$ \int_0^4 x^8 \, dx = \frac{x^9}{9} \Big|_0^4 = \frac{4^9}{9} \doteq 29127.111 $$
Now for the second integral.
\begin{align*}
a &= 4 \\
b &= 5 \\
n &= 4 \\
h &= \frac{b-a}{n} = \frac{5-4}{4} = \frac{1}{4} \\
S_2 &= \left( \frac{h}{3} \right) \left( f(4) + 4f\left(  \frac{17}{4} \right)  + 2f\left(  \frac{18}{4} \right)  +
 4f\left( \frac{19}{4} \right)  + f(5) \right) \\
f(4) &= 4^8 = 65536 \\
S_2 &= \left( \frac{1}{12} \right) \left( 65536 + 4f\left(  \frac{17}{4} \right)  + 2f\left(  \frac{18}{4} \right)  +
 4f\left( \frac{19}{4} \right)  + f(5) \right) \\
f\left(  \frac{17}{4} \right) &= \frac{17^8}{4^8} \doteq  106441.61 \\
S_2 &\doteq \left( \frac{1}{12} \right) \left( 65536 + 4( 106441.61  )  + 2f\left(  \frac{18}{4} \right)  +
 4f\left( \frac{19}{4} \right)  + f(5) \right) \\
S_2 &\doteq \left( \frac{1}{12} \right) \left( 491302.44  + 2f\left(  \frac{18}{4} \right)  +
 4f\left( \frac{19}{4} \right)  + f(5) \right) \\
f\left(  \frac{18}{4} \right) &= \left( \frac{ 9}{2} \right)^8  \doteq 168151.25 \\
f\left( \frac{19}{4} \right)  &= \left( \frac{ 19}{4} \right)^8  \doteq 259148.61 \\
f(5) &= 5^8 = 390625 \\
S_2 &\doteq \left( \frac{1}{12} \right) \left( 491302.44  + 2(  168151.25 )  +  4(  259148.61 )  + 390625 \right) \\
S_2 &\doteq \left( \frac{1}{12} \right) \left( 2254824.4 \right) \\
S_2 &\doteq 187902.03
\end{align*}
As a partial check, we compute the exact value of the integral.
$$ \int_4^5 x^8 \, dx = \frac{x^9}{9} \Big|_4^5 =  \frac{5^9}{9} -  \frac{4^9}{9} \doteq 187886.78 $$
Hence:
\begin{align*}
S &\doteq 29241.813  + 187902.03 \\
S &\doteq  217143.84 \\
\end{align*}
As a partial check, we compute the exact value of the integral.
$$ \int_0^5 x^8 \, dx = \frac{x^9}{9} \Big|_0^5 =  \frac{5^9}{9} = \frac{1953125 }{ 9} $$
$$ \int_0^5 x^8 \, dx \doteq  217013.89 $$

Comment: As a matter of style I would not align expressions which are talking about different things. That is \begin{align*} S_{1} &= \text{something}\dots f(1/2)\\ f(1/2) &= \text{something else}\end{align*} might suggest that $S_{1}$ is part of that "something else"

Comment: The splitting of the integrals depends on how your question is formulated. If you are asked to use simpsons rule with a uniform grid then you must make sure that when the partitions of the two integrals are put together, it indeed forms a uniform grid.

Comment: The reason Simpson's Rule exists really is to deal with integrals you cannot integrate (or cannot easily integrate) symbolically. So we have to ask what you're meant to do with an integral like this one, which easily computed exactly. My guess is you're supposed to use the error estimation formula for Simpson's Rule in order to choose a step size that is small enough, rather than use the exact value in order to determine the error. Then splitting the integral might allow a larger step in one part than in the other. But I think the previous comment is correct, that is not what was asked for.

Comment: @AndréArmatowski The idea of splitting the integral into two is to give the best possible precision with the least amount of work.

Comment: @DavidK I did this to get some practice with Simpson's rule.

Comment: I missed the part where you wrote, "a problem I made up". My mistake! A function you can integrate exactly is fine for this purpose. I would still suggest trying to deduce the number of steps to get <1% error by using an error estimation formula. At the end you can still do the comparison with the exact integral to see how well the formula worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea of splitting an integral into uneven partitions, usually based on how fast the derivative changes, is certainly a used tactic. Specifically in the case of numerical solutions for differential equations, of which numerical integration is a subset of, this is called an [adaptive step size](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adaptive_step_size).

As for your results, your Simpson approximations ought to have been

$$\int_0^4x^8~\mathrm dx\doteq\frac{2807249}{96}=29242.177083332$$
$$\int_4^5x^8~\mathrm dx\doteq\frac{18471521297}{98304}\doteq187902.03142293$$

so the first likely had an arithmetic error, but the second looks fine.